# How do I write the selenium IDE test case for generating a message to user?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am working on Selenium IDE for writing the test cases for a payment page. The payment page has a NEXT link. But click on the NEXT link is not able to proceed with the automation, What could be the best solution to go ahead with? If I insert a pause command and let the user click it manually,but i want that before clicking it manually it display a message to the user that you have to do this action manually. Then what is the command for carrying out that action? What are the best possible solutions with the complete commands ?

Comment: You need to show some code. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **break** command instead of **pause** command.

You can execute a Javascript to display a message.
    storeEval
    alert("Please click the Next Link")